# center a div to the page regardless of the element its contained within

Tags: html, css

I am making a data visualisation(vis) and I want the vis to have a key (like a sidebar) for the different colors. I have been doing this by making a div and floating it left and the vis floated to the right:

**HTML**

```
<div id="Container">
    <div id="key"></div>
    <div id="visContainer">
        <div id="vis"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#key{
    float:left;
    width:5%;
}
#visContainer{
    float: right;
    width: 95%;
}
#vis{
    outline: solid;
    outline-color: black;
}
```

But obviously the vis div will not always be centered on the screen. Is there a way to make this possible (i.e. have a centered vis that has a sidediv that does not impede on the centrality of the vis div)?

p.s. If possible I want to avoid using absolute positions as id like this to scale with the page size.

Comment: What's stopping you using absolute positions AND scaling with page size?

Comment: nothing i guess, but I have this feel bad thing about using absolute positions? am I right in thinking that you are effectively hard coding the position of the element (I.e. 10 pixels right and 20 pixels down on the screen sort of thing?)

Comment: You can use % based positioning, too - but I meant more of positioning both elements into a div, then you could position the elements where ever you wanted inside of that div.

Comment: If you set the parent container positioning to relative you can easily use absolute positioning to achieve the desired effect. This will also scale with the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use percentages to calculate the the center of the screen in the vis container element:

```
50% * 95% = 47.5%
```

That's where the center of your vis element should be. Now just subtract half of its width and you're good to go:

```
47.5% - (10% / 2) = 42.5%
```

See it here:

```css
#key{
    float:left;
    width:5%;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
#visContainer{
    float: right;
    width: 95%;
  height: 30px;
  background: cyan;
  position: relative;
}
#vis{
    outline: solid;
    outline-color: black;
  width: 10%;
  margin-left: 42.5%;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
    <div id="key"></div>
    <div id="visContainer">
        <div id="vis"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Of course, you can avoid all that math by using absolute position on the sidebar (it will still scale). Beware that now the 10% width of the vis element is 10% of the full body width since the container is 100% wide (going "under" the `#key` sidebar").

See it here:

```css
#key{
  position:absolute;
  z-index: 1;
    width:5%;
  height: 30px;
  background: yellow;
}
#visContainer{
  height: 30px;
  background: cyan;
  position: relative;
}
#vis{
    outline: solid;
    outline-color: black;
  width: 10%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="Container">
    <div id="key"></div>
    <div id="visContainer">
        <div id="vis"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: in your code snippet `vis` is only being centered to the `visContainer`, (i might be looking at it wrong). is there a way to center `vis` to the page rather than the center of its containing div?

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood, will update my answer in a minute.

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="main-block">
 <div id="Container">
   <div id="key">ddd</div>
     <div id="visContainer">
       <div id="vis">sss</div>
     </div>
   </div>
 </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.main-block{ 
  display: inline-block; 
  width: 100%; 
  text-align: center;
}

#container{
 width: 50%;
 display: inline-block;
}
```